# How to enable fast user switching at the Lock Screen in Gnome in RHEL 5.5

Tags: gnome, rhel-5

On RHEL 5.5 in Gnome, how can one enable the *Switch User* button in the *Lock Screen* dialog box? Ubuntu has this feature. I followed [a set of instructions for CentOS 5](http://jorgenmodin.net/index_html/archive/2008/03/12/how-to-enable-switch-user-in-gnome-on-centos-5/weblogentry_view) which didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found these lines somewhere as part of someone's custom GDM script. Works for me.

```
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory \
    --type bool --set "/desktop/gnome/lockdown/disable_user_switching" "false"
gconftool-2 --direct --config-source xml:readwrite:/etc/gconf/gconf.xml.mandatory \
    --type bool --set "/apps/gnome-screensaver/user_switch_enabled" "true"
```